# NodeJS request and error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `browsers.json` file I want to update on each deploy.

In case the request to update the file fails I would like to keep the original file unchanged.

Is this a good way to do it, or is there a "better practise" way?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = 'http://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/info/browsers/webdriver';

if (fs.existsSync('browsers.json')){ 
    var browsers = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('browsers.json'));
}

http.get(url, function (res) {
    var data = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        fs.writeFile('browsers.json', data, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    })

}).on("error", function () {
    fs.writeFile('browsers.json', browsers, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Comment: "In case the request to update the file occurs I would like to keep the original file unchanged."  What do you mean?  You mean if the file already exists, do nothing?

Comment: @Brad, I meant _fails_, sorry. Corrected. I mean if the request fails I want to not re-write the browsers file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that on error, you shouldn't be writing anything.  I would also say that it is generally best just to pipe the response directly to a writable stream on the file, so that you aren't buffering the whole thing in memory.  (Although, that might not matter much if your file is small.)

Finally, don't forget to re-parse and load the data once you have it.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I do re-parse and load the data on a separated file, this is to be run in the packager.json script. I am not so "at home" with node, so I ask: if there is a error in the `http.get()` is `res.on('end'` executed at all?

Comment: @Sergio Yes, if you have a response stream then `end` will always fire at some point.  Also, be sure to check your response status code, to make sure you have a `200`.